# Does two sets of three numbers have at least two numbers in common?

Tags: algorithm

I just had to write a function that seemed simple to write, but when I actually did it, it turned out way gorier than I had expected. It's really bugging me, I feel like there's a better solution, but my brain is going crazy trying to think of it, so therefore I'm turning to you fine folks.

Basically, I have 2 triangles, and I want to know if they share a common edge. The triangles are indexed by their vertices (i.e. their vertices is just an index to an array containing the actual coordinates), so it comes down to finding if two sets of three numbers have two numbers in common. I.e. triangles (1,2,3) and (3,1,5) do share an edge, the (1,3) edge. However, triangles (1,2,3) and (1,5,6) does not share an edge (only a vertex) and neither does (1,2,3) and (4,5,6).

How would you write this "two numbers in common function"? You can assume all values inside each set are distinct (i.e. (1, 1, 2) is not going to be an input) and you can also assume that two sets don't equal each other (i.e. I'm not going to compare (1,2,3) and (1,3,2), because those two are the same triangle). However, no assumptions can be made regarding order, they are not sorted or anything like that.

This is basically what I came up with (assuming the sets are (x0, x1, x2) and (y0, y1, y2)):

```
// If the x0 is equal to any of (y0, y1, y2), make sure at least one of (x1, x2)
// is equal to one of the y numbers
if (x0 == y0) {
    return x1 == y1 || x1 == y2 || x2 == y1 || x2 == y2;
} else if (x0 == y1) {
    return x1 == y0 || x1 == y2 || x2 == y0 || x2 == y2;
} else if (x0 == y2) {
    return x1 == y0 || x1 == y1 || x2 == y0 || x2 == y1;
} else {

    // if x0 is not equal to any of (y0, y1, y2), then x1 and x2 both have
    // to be equal to two of the y numbers. 
    return (x1 == y0 && x2 == y1) 
        || (x1 == y0 && x2 == y2)
        || (x1 == y1 && x2 == y0)
        || (x1 == y1 && x2 == y2)
        || (x1 == y2 && x2 == y0)
        || (x1 == y2 && x2 == y1);
}
```

but it feels so gory to me! So many branches and such long boolean statements! I feel like i'm missing an obvious easy solution, and it's driving me insane.

In addition, this happens in an inner loop in a very performance sensitive application, so performance (branching, arithmetic, whatever) matters.

BTW, the code I'm writing is C#, but the question is the same in more or less any imperative language.

EDIT:

I put together a quick benchmark (here's the [code](https://gist.github.com/OskarSigvardsson/05be9f302811cf8393ee579c8fdad9aa)) with the suggestions so far. Here are the results (running it at a million random pairs of triangles):

```
Original method result:         7035, time elapsed in ms:   8.6252
qwertyman method result:        7035, time elapsed in ms:   8.2537
midjji method result:           7035, time elapsed in ms:   8.7984
Single HashSet method result:   7035, time elapsed in ms:   184.4984
Many HashSets method result:    7035, time elapsed in ms:   190.5785
```

The numbers remain fairly consistent run to run, with @qwertyman's method always being a bit faster than my original version or @midjii's. It also has the advantage of being the cleanest and nicest of them all, so I'm going to go with that one.

I was actually a bit surprised that the "Many HashSets" was so close to "Single HashSet", I would have thought constructing a million HashSets would have a bigger overhead than around 16 milliseconds (though this obviously doesn't count the increased pressure on the garbage collector), though they're both obviously far behind the other methods.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: A lot depends on how you represent your sets. Also, are they true sets? (Guaranteed that elements are unique)

Comment: Depending on the language you are using, just store the numbers in actual sets, and use library function to calculate the size of the intersection.

Comment: I'm using C#, but it doesn't really matter what language you answer in, any is fine. The sets are just variables named (x0, x1, x2) and (y0, y1, y2). And no, NO WAY am I going to create two set datastructures on the heap, then run the intersection method on them and check length, that's a crazy solution. I need it to be way faster than that.

Comment: @Oskar: If high performance is a key factor you should mention that in the question. As it is your complaint on your current method seems to be nothing to do with speed but with how it doesn't look good - this is more likely to encourage people to give algorithms that are readable rather than high performance.

Comment: I understand your performance requirement but, just for the fun of it, did you actually benchmark your approach against something like a `HashSet` and determined the latter is going to be horrendously slow?

Comment: @chris I would have thought "this happens in an inner loop in a very performance sensitive application, so performance (branching, arithmetic, whatever) matters" would have been clear enough.

Comment: @s.m No, I didn't, but I can't imagine that creating that that would be faster. It's in an inner loop, so you would have to create a lot of HashSets (generating a lot of garbage), or just create one and keep clearing it. That has to be slower than just a few branches, right? But you're right, I should try it just to see what the difference is.

Comment: Sure, it's not a matter of `HashSet` having many chances of being faster (I too can't imagine it would perform better), I'm just curious as to how much slower it could be. Also, it could be worthwhile trying both to instantiate a lot of sets vs reusing one.

Comment: @s.m I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Thank you, that would be awesome.

Comment: If performance matters it is probably beneficial to ensure the indexes of the triangles are saved in order. A little more work for saving triangles but it is easier/faster to compare them.

Comment: @maraca you're not wrong, but unfortunately that's not an option, I have to keep the triangles as they are.

Comment: @s.m posted a benchmark of the various methods

Comment: @Oskar: I actually managed to miss that in the original post, sorry. I still think it could do with being a bit clearer. I think (and its bad of me I know) that when you started saying "So many branches and such long boolean statements!" that I decided we were into fluff now and I'd read all the actual question bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int n = 0;

// check if x0 is among the values in the second set
if (x0 == y0 || x0 == y1 || x0 == y2) {
    n++;
}

// check if x1 is among the values in the second set
if (x1 == y0 || x1 == y1 || x1 == y2) {
    n++;
}

// check if x2 is among the values in the second set
if (x2 == y0 || x2 == y1 || x2 == y2) {
    n++;
}

return n >= 2;
```

This relies on the fact that (as you mentioned) the numbers in each set are distinct, resulting in a simpler logic.

---

If you are using C, you could write it shorter:

```
int n = 0;

n += x0 == y0 || x0 == y1 || x0 == y2;
n += x1 == y0 || x1 == y1 || x1 == y2;
n += x2 == y0 || x2 == y1 || x2 == y2;

return n >= 2;
```

Comment: In your second C example, would it be faster to convert the || to addition, to avoid branching due to short-circuiting?

Comment: BTW, i realize that we're talking about teeny micro-optimizations at this point, but I really need the code to be as fast as possible. Also, I'm curious :)

Comment: It made me curious as well -- I made a benchmark and first set the numbers in [0, 300], and the times were quite similar, with a very slight advantage for the "||" variant. However, the short-circuiting occurred quite rarely. Afterwards I also made an experiment with the x and y values in [0, 15] and the "+" variant was faster (probably because here the short-circuits occur more often, being harder to predict the branch).

Comment: but the question is interesting because it is not an optimization that could be made automatically by a compiler (simply converting the || to +) -- in general the result would not be the same, but in this case it is, because we know that the input numbers in the same set are different.

Comment: How did you write the shortcut variant? If you substitute the stuff in the first if with A, 2nd B and 3rd C it should be something like: if (A) return B || C; else if (B) return C; else return false;

Comment: @maraca I used the C code from the answer -- the short-circuiting occurs due to the "||" operator (with no other explicit coding for it). For example in the expression "x0 == y0 || x0 == y1 || x0 == y2", if the first condition is true (i.e. x0 == y0), then the next ones are not evaluated.

Comment: @qwertyman I see, but in my opinion it is not the optimal version. You always check all indexes, but you don't need to if the first two checks are both true or false then the last check can be skipped entirely. And if the first check is true B || C can shortcut already on the first of 6 comparisons.

Comment: Shortened: if (A) return B || C; else return (B) && (C);

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
...
{
  //ti= xi in y 
  bool t0= (x0==y0) ||(x0==y1)|| (x0==y2);
  bool t1= (x1==y0) ||(x1==y1)|| (x1==y2);
  bool t2= (x2==y0) ||(x2==y1)|| (x2==y2);

  return (t0 && t1) || (t0 && t2) || (t1 && t2);
}
```

Mostly because I think its easier to read.

Performance-wise it is rather likely that with the right settings it should be as fast. Compilers are fantastic at optimizing self enclosed, no side effect, logical statements and use lazy evaluation for bool(assuming nothing silly has been done to ==).